# Partially applied type lambda in Scala with kind projector

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types, partial-application, kind-projector

Consider the following type definition:

```
trait LiftF[F[_], G[_]] {
  def liftF[A](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}
```

When providing a requirement for an implicit of this type in context bounds (using kind projector plugin) we have to write it like this:

```
def func[A, G[_], F[_]: LiftF[?[_], G]](a: F[A]): G[A]
```

I would like to get rid of the `?[_]` part, so my initial guess was to write a type `To[G[_]]` that returns `LiftF[?[_], G]` in order to transform the above function definition into

```
def func[A, G[_], F[_]: LiftF.To[G]](a: F[A]): G[A]
```

However, when writing type `To` definition as

```
type To[G[_]] = LiftF[?[_], G]
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Error:(17, 20) type Λ$ takes type parameters
type To[G[_]] = LiftF[?[_], G]
```

Trying to rewrite it with existential types produces the following type definition:

```
type To[G[_]] = LiftF[F, G] forSome { type F[X] }
```

This compiles fine but, unsuprisingly, can't be applied to other type parameters, so desired function definition can't be achieved.

I managed to implement the "partial application" part with code inspired by the aux pattern:

```
trait To[G[_]] {
  type From[F[_]] = LiftF[F, G]
}
```

Sadly enough, this leaves me with syntax that is arguably worse than the original one:

```
def func[A, G[_], F[_]: LiftF.To[G]#From](a: F[A]): G[A]
```

My question is - can I achieve the originally proposed syntax in Scala with the help of kind projector or I should just stick with `?[_]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the kind-projector can't really help you here:

```
type To[G[_]] = LiftF[?[_], G]
```

would simply be mechanically rewritten into something like

```
type To[G[_]] = ({ type T[F[_]] = LiftF[F, G] })#T
```

but it's invalid in 2.12.x, because it expects a plain type of kind `*` on the right hand side of the definition.

If you move the parameter `F` to the left hand side, you end up with

```
type To[G[_], F[_]] = LiftF[F, G]
```

which you then have to use as `To[G, ?[_]]`, which obviously doesn't buy you anything either, it simply swaps the order of arguments. Therefore I'd suggest to just use `LiftF[?[_], G]` and take solace from the fact that you don't have to write out `({ type L[F[_]] = LiftF[F, G] })#L` explicitly.

---

By the way, in Dotty, this works just fine:

```
trait LiftF[F[_], G[_]] {
  def liftF[A](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}

type To[G[_]] = [F[_]] => LiftF[F, G]
def f[A, G[_], F[_]: To[G]](a: F[A]): G[A] = implicitly[LiftF[F, G]].liftF(a)
```

Comment: Beautiful, I wish Dotty was acknowledged more than it is.

Comment: Thanks for the Dotty tip. Probably this will be the reason to finally try it out.

Comment: Syntax changed from `=>` to `=>>` by [Use =>> for type lambdas #6558](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/6558)